# To get the value of specific attribute value as True or False, having uneven columns

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep, xml

I am having one file with the below two lines in the file. I need to check if the value of xpoweredBy is true or false. Many thanks in advance.

```
    <Connector clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" xpoweredBy="false" allowTrace="false" />
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" xpoweredBy="false" allowTrace="false" />
```

Comment: Try it with the appoach from the answer to your other question. The explanation should help you adapt the answer to this problem. If you have trouble with it, post your attempt so we can assist.

Comment: @Philippos
This issue is slightly different. I have two tags with uneven columns or may be having multiple lines within that tag.
The issue is, I am not able to get the specific value of xpowerdBy parameter as true or false.

Comment: Extracting the value of `xpoweredBy` is analogous to the other answer. If the tag can be split over lines and `xpoweredBy` can also appear in different tags, it's a different issue. Your question and your example should reflect that. Split over two lines at most or even more?

Comment: @Philippos
As I specified, the xpoweredBy will be there in the Container tag itself.
just need to know if the value of xpoweredBy is true or false using shell script.
Can you please help me in this ?

Comment: If the string `xpoweredBy` is found nowhere but in that tag, it's simply `sed -n 's_.*xpoweredBy="\([^"]*\)".*_\1_p'`, just like in the other answer.

Comment: @Philippos I need one help of yours. Can you please help me with the case where there is a space between the attribute and its value 
ex : xpoweredBy (space)  = (space)  "false"

Comment: Simply add the spaces to the pattern

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a well-formed XML document, maybe something like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <Connector clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" xpoweredBy="false" allowTrace="false"/>
  <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" xpoweredBy="false" allowTrace="false"/>
</root>
```

then you may use XMLStarlet to extract the values of all the `Connector` nodes' `xpoweredBy` attribute with

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//Connector/@xpoweredBy' -nl file.xml
false
false
```

The XPath expression `//Connector/@xpoweredBy` would select all `xpoweredBy` attributes of every single `Connector` node in the whole document, and XMLStarlet would print those values newline-separated.